# how to get a nested json like this with node.js and mysql?

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I have a table "pages" and a table "sections" I'd like to get this in json:

```
[
{name:"something",sections:[{"id":1,"name":"asd"},{"id":1,"name":"asd"}...etc]}
]
```

what's the best way to do this? a mysql query? a simple page query and then pushing into it the sections?

Comment: ...how are you creating and retrieving the json in the first place?

Comment: You can do it using concat  --select concat("{\"id\":",id,",\"name\":",name,"}") as sectionJson from section;

Comment: You will need to do the same with both the tables join them and then use group_concat to create array of section inside page json

Comment: I do something like this connection.query('SELECT * FROM pages where ? ', condicion, function(err, rows){        
  if (err) 
   callback(err,null);
  else
   if (rows[0]==undefined) {
    callback(null,null);
   }else{   
    callback(null,rows);        
           }
    });